# Fastest way to check if a object attribute is in a list, if yes do something and write it to output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long list of objects (>1M) with one of the attributes that need to be compared with a list, and if it matches one of the list elements, I want to add another attribute and write out the object to a file.

So far I was using

```
mols_cons_2 = [mol for mol in mols_2 if mol.title in cons_mol]
for mol in mols_cons_2:
    "add new attribute here"
    out_2.write(mol)
```

where `mols_2` is a list of objects, `mol.title` is the attribute and `cons_mol` the list where `mol.title` is compared. In this way, I have to read both `mols_2` and `mols_cons_2`, while I would like to merge the second cycle in the first (i.e. if `mol` is in `mols_2` and `mol.title` in `cons_mol`, add new attribute and write to `out_2`. Any suggestion on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned more than 1 million elements to check for, which means using a list membership check would be terribly inefficient.

One fast way to do this in python is using `set` data structure. Firstly, create a set with the list you already have. Then do membership check using `in`. This is faster than doing membership checking in `list` as it only allow insertion of unique elements.

```py
attributes = [1, 2, 3]
attribute_set = set(attributes)
objects = [Obj1, Obj2]

for obj in objects:
    if obj.title in attribute_set:
        do_something()
    out_2.write(mol)
```

The following is the benchmark between list membership check and set membership check.

```py
import timeit

target = [_ for _ in range(100000)]
s = set(target)
l = target


print("set membership check: ", timeit.timeit(lambda: 10001 in s))
print("list membership check: ", timeit.timeit(lambda: 10001 in l))
```

This is the result on my machine.

```
set membership check: 0.06143619100021169
list membership check: 94.21448056700001
```

Comment: Thanks @thu! I am testing it out...I guess in your cycle, it should be `if obj.title in attributes_set` instead of if `obj.title in attributes`, am I right?

Comment: @FG89 yep. My mistake, I've modified it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine the loops, right? Just use an if-statement as a filter:

```
for mol in mols_2:
    if mol.title in cons_mol:
        mol.new_attribute = 'eggs'  # Example attribute add
        out_2.write(mol)
```

This saves creating the list `mols_cons_2`.